# Disable Chrome's default headers & footers in headless print-to-pdf

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

I got a multipage HTML document, which I want to export to PDF using headless Google Chrome / Chromium from the command line: `chrome --headless --print-to-pdf [...]`. The issue with this is, that Chrome adds auto-generated headers and footers to the page when "printing". Others have suggested using `@page {margin: 0}` in my CSS, but as some others also stated, that only works for a few pages for some magic reason, hence there's a footer on the last page of my example.

I am aware of an [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-headless-render-pdf) that supports export without headers, but that export takes around 30% more time than headless Chrome itself and would require installing and setting up NPM and the package on my company's servers.

If anyone knows any way to hide Google Chrome's default headers / footers on headless PDF-export by CSS or some setting, please let me know.

---

By the way, since I did not figure out another solution, I went with the [NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-headless-render-pdf) instead. It's been working very well and reliably so far, it just took about 30% more time in my tests, so keep that in mind.

Comment: I've been scouring the internet an answer to this question too. Google built a Node.js solution called Puppeteer which allows you to pass options to create custom headers/footers or to disable them entirely. CLI is simply not supported, so there's no way to remove this useless debug information. I wish they would have just disabled this garbage by default, it causes so much extra work and magical code just to remove this anti-feature.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There is an option available in Google Chrome: `--no-pdf-header-footer`   (or `--print-to-pdf-no-header` for older versions of Chrome).

```bash
canary \
  --headless \
  --disable-gpu \
  --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw \
  --no-pdf-header-footer \
  --print-to-pdf-no-header \
  --print-to-pdf=example.pdf \
  http://example.com
```

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/chromium/new-headless

Comment: This new option is very interesting. I found the [commit reference](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/731c566fb3cc28fb9159a99f955082b9e8649209). However, I didn't find in which _version number_ of Chrome it got released (if it did).

Comment: Indeed, I'm on Chromium 83 (released in mid May, while the patch is from mid April) from Debian, and the `--print-to-pdf-no-header` has no effect (but no error either....).

Comment: Using Google Chrome 89.0.4379.0 canary I was able to get this to work using `--headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=output1.pdf --print-to-pdf-no-header`.

Comment: This will frustratingly disable _both_ the header and the footer. Is there a way to _only_ disable the header?

Comment: I know `--print-to-pdf-no-header` is available in Chromium 87

Comment: On newer Chrome `--print-to-pdf-no-header` option is deprecated in preference of `--no-pdf-header-footer`

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077392/additional-options-in-chrome-headless-print-to-pdf) could help you. basically you need to add CSS bellow

```
@media print {
  @page { margin: 0; }
  body { margin: 1.6cm; }
}
```

and the "**--no-margins**" parameter

Comment: As (somewhat) stated in my question, I've tried this one already. (Also with --no-margins)

Comment: Are you with the latest version of Google Chrome?

Comment: Sure. Just for clarification: Setting `margin: 0` does work for 1 or 2 pages, but when I try it with like 20 pages or something, the footer on the last page is visible.

Comment: I can also confirm this exact behavior that @d0n.key is experiencing with the footer remaining.