# How to print webpage to pdf without timestamp?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-headless

The following shows how to print a webpage to pdf using chrome.

[additional options in Chrome headless print-to-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46077392/additional-options-in-chrome-headless-print-to-pdf)

But there is timestamp at the top of the pdf. Is there a way to disable the timestamp? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Chrome headless debugging API.

https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/

There are some nice wrappers around it, like this package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-headless-render-pdf