# How to add custom footer with page number in pdf generation using headless chrome

Tags: php, laravel, google-chrome-headless

Can anyone help me to add a footer in pdf generation using headless chrome??

I used headless chrome which generates pdf from HTML file. This process happens in the background of laravel.

Every thing works fine but don't know how to add custom footer with page number.

Comment: Not sure what you are using exactly but I use the chrome remote interface and the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49147539/487813 (also not sure why this is tagged PHP and Laravel)

Comment: Using headless chrome is like telling chrome to print to a pdf. You should check chrome printing options. But I think you can only turn on/off footer/header printing: https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/104293547/hello-how-can-i-edit-my-headers-and-footers?hl=en
If you need a more flexible way to make the pdf consider using one of the php library like FPDF or TCPDF. Alternatively, you can edit the chrome pdf file with one of the above library and add the footer you need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alter the default header/footer when printing to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44575628/alter-the-default-header-footer-when-printing-to-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this command for headless chrome 'google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf-no-header --no-sandbox --print-to-pdf='.$pdfFilePath.$pdfFile.' '.$pdfUrl;'

Comment: Adding a custom footer with a page number in PDF generation using headless Chrome, you have to make use of Chrome DevTools Protocol (CDP) with Puppeteer, which is a Node library that provides a high-level API to control headless Chrome.